# HD Processor Graphics (HD4000) failed to load as a device in Intel OpenCL SDK

Tags: opencl, intel

I'm using i7-3770K Ivy Bridge with HD 4000, and I've installed the latest drivers and the newest [OpenCL SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/vcsource-tools-opencl-sdk/).

When tried to run the code samples with CPU, it works just fine. However, when I set the '-g' parameter to run with the processing graphics, the device cannot be found hence it exited with code -1 (which is likely caused by failing to create a CL context).

SimpleOptimization, GodRays, and all codes that support Intel Processor Graphics failed to run with the HD4000.

I am using Windows 7 64-bit, MSVS VC++ 2008 express edition.

[GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.geeks3d.com/20120427/intel-ivy-bridge-hd-graphics-4000-gpu-opengl-and-opencl-tests/3/) also could not detect Intel HD Graphics as the Intel OpenCL device.

In addition, when I run [DirectX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6812) code samples, the Intel HD 4000 was detected perfectly and it run the code just fine with the HD Graphics.

And I also have an nvidia card on my system which runs as the graphical driver.

Any idea how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem based on a statement of SE in Intel. Now the HD Graphics run perfect as an OpenCL device.

```
"I also have an nvidia card on my system which runs as the graphical driver."
```

> [Maxim Shevtsov (Intel)](http://software.intel.com/en-us/profile/453760/): Likely this is the actual root-cause.
>   Currently Processor Graphics OCL device in unavailable in the
>   "headless" configuration (without a monitor plugged in).

And this is the Q&A in Intel forum and the answer, I hope this is useful for someone who encounters this problem:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=105793&p=1#187037